# Cursor is always placed before the paper clip icon when file is inserted in Froala editors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, froala

**Step to reproduce::**

1. Open [Froala link](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor)
2. Clear editors.
3. Click on the file icon and select file.
4. **Issue**:: Cursor is always placed before the paper clip icon.

**Acceptance Criteria::** Cursor is placed after a paper clip icon when a file is attached to editors.

Video::

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the paper clip issue using your repro steps. Is it possible you have edited your css in some way ?

Comment: Thanks for the first response. I reproduce the same issue in froala website.

Comment: ok - to confirm then: Using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and following your link to froala website then following your steps (both drag-and-drop file AND file select via explorer) I cannot get the same to happen. Please review your repro - maybe try it on another browser or machine , or set up a fiddle or snippet. I would love to help but cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/tester9065/9vd83dgj/129/        chromium-browser: 69.0.3497.81-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500

Comment: Tried with your sample at  jsfiddle.net/tester9065/9vd83dgj/129  and it still does not reproduce your video example.

Comment: Thanks for giving time to reproduce issue from your side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has occurred in some browsers. I have applied one trick to solve the problem.

**Triggered before uploading a file to the server.**

```
$('.selector').on('froalaEditor.file.beforeUpload', function (e, editor, files) {
  // Code....
});
```

**Triggered after the request to upload a file has been completed successfully.**

```
$('.selector').on('froalaEditor.file.inserted', function (e, editor, $file, response) {
  editor.html.insert(" "); //add extra space after successfully file uploaded.
});
```